# Why are failed transactions kept in node storage when querying eth_getTransaction...?

Tags: transactions, evm, json-rpc

I'm querying an Alchemy node to get all the transactions from a single block. However, I see that it returns failed transactions. Why are these kept in the node's storage, and do they reflect only the failed transactions that the miner was able to include, or could there be failed transactions that never make it into the block?

Answer (score 0):

Failed transactions are also part of the Ethereum blockchain. This is because even for failed transactions a gas fee is paid. This fee payment is a state change and needs to be kept track of in the blockchain.

If a transaction would fail because the fee payment cannot be made or the nonce is not in order anymore, then the transaction will not be included in the block and will also be removed from the mempool (the queue of new transaction, that need to be mined).

Comment: will all failed transactions be propogated across the network ? Or are failed transactions treated equally(from a  networks perspective) as normal transactions